# Micro cloudfoundry issues after power outage

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry

So I forgot to plug my laptop back in last night and my laptop lost power killing my micro instance without a nice shutdown.  Now when I start the micro instance, everything in the console looks ok, but I can't connect to the monogodb instance.  I assumed that this was probably because the mongod.lock file got left hanging around, so I went to find that and deleted it from here:

```
/var/vcap/store/mongodb/a925311a-2145-4a50-b103-e243da010e7c/data/mongod.lock
```

Then I couldn't figure out how to restart the service (anyone know??), so I just rebooted the VM.  I still can't get a connection.  Before I removed the lock and tried to tunnel, I would get this error:

```
vmc tunnel mongo-xxx
1: none
2: mongorestore
3: mongo
4: mongodump
Which client would you like to start?> 3

Opening tunnel on port 10000... OK
Waiting for local tunnel to become available... OK
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: localhost:10000/db
Tue Jan 29 09:11:49 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Jan 29 09:11:49 Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: localhost:10000 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:93
exception: connect failed
'mongo' execution failed; is it in your $PATH?
```

Now after I restarted, I get this error:

```
vmc tunnel mongo-xxx
1: none
2: mongorestore
3: mongo
4: mongodump
Which client would you like to start?> 3

Opening tunnel on port 10000... FAILED
CFoundry::ServiceGatewayError: 503: Unexpected response from service gateway
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash
```

What are the correct step to fix your micro instance after a bad shutdown?

Thanks

EDIT: I found another error in the mongodb log:

```
Tue Jan 29 16:28:43 [initandlisten] options: { auth: "true", bind_ip: "0.0.0.0", config: "/var/vcap/store/mongodb/a925311a-2145-4a50-b103-e243da010e7c/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/vcap/store/mongodb/a925311a-2145-4a50-b103-e243da010e7c/data", logpath: "/var/vcap/sys/service-log/mongodb/a925311a-2145-4a50-b103-e243da010e7c/mongodb.log", maxConns: 500, nohttpinterface: "true", nojournal: true, noprealloc: "true", port: 25001, quota: "true", quotaFiles: 4, smallfiles: "true" }
**************
Error: journal files are present in journal directory, yet starting without --journal enabled.
It is recommended that you start with journaling enabled so that recovery may occur.
**************
```

But looking in the monogodb.conf file says:

```
# journaling is currently preallocating 4G of space on disk
# we can't do that.
#
#journal    = true
```

So I'm not sure that will work.  I'm starting to think I just need to delete the service and recreate it, but that seems like a crappy solution...

Comment: Did you try starting with journaling enabled? That will try to recover your crashed db from the journal.

Comment: Do you know how to do that in cloudfoundry?  I tried changing it in the mongodb.conf, restarted the vm and when it came up, the config file was back the way it was.  I assume it is configured elsewhere, but I don't know where...

Comment: So it looks like you can get it to work by editing: /var/vcap/jobs/mongodb_node/config/mongodb_node.yml

Comment: Glad it worked out - Sorry I did not have any idea about cloudfoundry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working now.  I believe it was a combination of:

1) removing the mongod.lock file at: `/var/vcap/store/mongodb/a925311a-2145-4a50-b103-e243da010e7c/data/mongod.lock`

2) editing /var/vcap/jobs/mongodb_node/config/mongodb_node.yml and changing the mongo_options from:

```
mongod_options:
  "1.8": ""
  "2.0": "--nojournal"
```

to

```
mongod_options:
  "1.8": ""
  "2.0": "--journal"
```

I also found that if I killed the `mongodb_node` process, it restarted it's self and then mongod started running.